# What are the ramifications of nailing my sleeveless sweater to the wall?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

I took my sleeveless sweater and nailed it into the wall. It's set in there pretty darn good.

So I'm just wondering, are there any ramifications now that it is a vest kavua?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Let's see... Make sure to remove the nails before washing it ...

Comment: ... Your intuition for what counts as "pretty darn good" is insufficient. You need a sophisticated, kosher-certified, computer program to model the number and spacing of the nails. ...

Comment: You shouldn't get any new vests until you get rid of your _vest kavua_.

Comment: Well, if you're stapling your clothes to the wall, a siman hefsek is the least of your problems...

Comment: .... downvotes?

Comment: Hilarious. !  !   !!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Keeping one's vest in check seems to be a full time job! I just started reading this book that my rabbi recommended when I asked him for a Jewish book that doesn't talk about God on every other page, and the whole first chapter is the author complaining over and over about "my vest." It's coming. It's not coming. It's never coming again. Sheesh! I prefer your decisive method - just hang it up once, and be done with it. That way, you won't have to argue with it about where it goes. I hope the people in this book learn this technique at some point. There's this guy they call "the man" who keeps picking fights with people.

Comment: Wow took me a minute. Awesome.

Comment: @Yez, seriously, though, the dominance of that word - repeated seven times - and a select set of accompanying words in the first chapter is striking. I just noticed that in looking for something to jokingly misquote, but now, I want to investigate that element for real.

Comment: You should email Rabbi Fohrman, sounds like the kind of thing that would be right up his alley

Answer (score 6):

The ramifications are:

A: You now have a question for Mi Yodeya.

B: You seriously need a psychiatrist.

C: You need to purchase a new sleeveless sweater.

D: You only have to Chosesh for that vest, as all the other vests are off the wall.

Comment: E: You need to check for blood.

Comment: Check the holes in your walls for tzaraat.

Answer (score 2):

A vest in Hebrew is an אפוד. We learn in Shmot 28:15:

> וְעָשִׂיתָ חֹשֶׁן מִשְׁפָּט, מַעֲשֵׂה חֹשֵׁב--כְּמַעֲשֵׂה אֵפֹד, תַּעֲשֶׂנּוּ
>
> And you shall make a breastplate (חושן) of justice, the work of a craftsman; like the making of the vest (אפוד) shall you make it.

Now, the חושן was embedded with twelve stones. Thus, by reverse comparison, the אפוד must be embedded with twelve stones. Although this did not actually happen, it was fulfilled because the איפוד and the חושן were attached (28:23-25):

> כג וְעָשִׂיתָ, עַל-הַחֹשֶׁן, שְׁתֵּי, טַבְּעוֹת זָהָב; וְנָתַתָּ, אֶת-שְׁתֵּי הַטַּבָּעוֹת, עַל-שְׁנֵי, קְצוֹת הַחֹשֶׁן.  כד וְנָתַתָּה, אֶת-שְׁתֵּי עֲבֹתֹת הַזָּהָב, עַל-שְׁתֵּי, הַטַּבָּעֹת--אֶל-קְצוֹת, הַחֹשֶׁן.  כה וְאֵת שְׁתֵּי קְצוֹת שְׁתֵּי הָעֲבֹתֹת, תִּתֵּן עַל-שְׁתֵּי הַמִּשְׁבְּצוֹת; וְנָתַתָּה עַל-כִּתְפוֹת הָאֵפֹד, אֶל-מוּל פָּנָיו.
>
> 23 And thou shalt make upon the breastplate two rings of gold, and shalt put the two rings on the two ends of the breastplate. 24 And thou shalt put the two wreathen chains of gold on the two rings at the ends of the breastplate. 25 And the other two ends of the two wreathen chains thou shalt put on the two settings, and put them on the shoulder-pieces of the ephod, in the forepart thereof.

In our days, many ignore this halacha. However, your nailing of the vest to the wall could help you in this area-- if your walls contains exactly twelve stones.

You have completed step one of this mitzvah; once you inlay twelve stones into your wall, you will have completed it fully. But you must hurry to do the second step, for Chazal said:

> המחבר את אפודו לדבר, כל שעה ושעה שאין שתים עשרה אבנים נתונות בו, מעלה עליו הכתוב כאילו מתחייב בנפשו
>
> One who connects his vest to something, every hour that twelve stones are not inside it (the connected thing) Scripture considers it as if he has forfeited his life (Talmud Bubbly, Masechet Baba Mayseh, Daf 1a).

The Rambam also codifies it as Mitzvah #614.

Comment: I didn't realize this was a reference to a וסת קבוע, but I think my answer it still pretty okay.

Answer (score 1):

Well if God forbid you'd ever have to tear your garments in mourning, you've already satisfied the requirement as if you'd torn this sweater right in two down the middle -- as *kol kavua, kemechtza al mechtza damya.*

Actually, there is an expert rabbi to be consulted on these matters, and he's also a watchmaker. His name is Dayan Shaatan, shlit'a.

Little did you realize it, but the Noda Bihuda observed that one of those nails actually triggered a Rube Goldberg contraption locking a cat into a compartment in which it will be poisoned if an atom decays. (This was actually Bigtan and Teresh's plan for King Achashverosh, by the way, but that's a story [for another time](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).) The cat's probably not dead yet, but probably will be soon.